# why uploading api is not called in chrome

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, file-upload

I am using this uploader for uploading file http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('content-uploader'),
      action: 'http://myserver ip or domain/yapi/index.php?_command=newcontent'
      ,onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
        var params={
          '_userid':App.currentUser.data.userid
        };
                uploader.setParams(params);
            },
      onComplete: function(id, fileName, content_data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(content_data)+JSON.stringify(fileName)+JSON.stringify(id));
        Content.addone(content_data);
      }
});
```

when i upload from firefox it calls my api and gives the result but from chrome it doesn't giving result it gives blank content why ?

Comment: problem was in the php api and chrome doesn't show the result of api or error as firebug